# Count half of rest of a partition by from position

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, window-functions

I'm trying to achieve the following results:

[image]

now, the group comes from

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum <= (0.5 * seqnum_rev) THEN i.[P&L] END) OVER(PARTITION BY i.bracket_label ORDER BY i.event_id) AS [P&L 50%],
```

I need that in each iteration it counts the total of rows from the end till position (seq_inv) and sum the amounts in P&L only for the half of it from that position.

for example, when

```
seq = 2
```

seq_inv will be = 13, half of it is 6 so I need to sum the following 6 positions from seq = 2.

when seq = 4  there are 11 positions till the end (seq_inv = 11), so half is 5, so I want to count 5 positions from seq = 4.

I hope this makes sense, I'm trying to come up with a rule that will be able to adapt to the case I have, since the partition by is what gives me the numbers that need to be summed.

I was also thinking if there was something to do with a partition by top 50% or something like that, but I guess that doesn't exist.

Comment: Can't really understand the range well. For example, the yellow one, how does the range 3-8 happen?

Comment: @TheImpaler from the range 3 till the end, there are 12 rows, half of it is 6,  so I'm summarizing 6 position from position 3

Comment: @Baldie47 . . . You should set up a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Purple box is five rows of `-1`, yet the result is given as `3.76`.  Yellow box is six rows of `-1` and one row of `0.6`, yet the result is given as `10.64`.  With requirements that are hard to word it is ***imperative*** that the example data and example results are actually correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the advantage that I've helped him before and have a little extra context.

That context is that this is just the later stage of a very long chain of common table expressions.  That means self-joins and/or correlated sub-queries are unfortunately expensive.

Preferably, this should be answerable using window functions, as the data set is already available in the appropriate ordering and partitioning.

My reading is this...

The `SUM(5:9)` *(meaning the sum of rows 5 to row 9, inclusive)* is equal to `SUM(5:end) - SUM(10:end)`

That leads me to this...

```
WITH
  cumulative AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM([P&L]) OVER (PARTITION BY bracket_label ORDER BY event_id DESC)  AS cumulative_p_and_l
  FROM
    data
)
SELECT
  *,
  cum_val - LEAD(cumulative_p_and_l, seq_inv/2, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY bracket_label ORDER BY event_id)  AS p_and_l_50_perc,
  cum_val - LEAD(cumulative_p_and_l, seq_inv/4, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY bracket_label ORDER BY event_id)  AS p_and_l_25_perc,
FROM
  cumulative
```

***NOTE: Using , `&`, `%` in column names is horrendous, don't do it ;)***

**EDIT:** Corrected the `ORDER BY` in the cumulative sum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that window functions can do what you want. You could use a correlated subquery instead, with the following logic:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select  sum(t1.P&L] 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.seq - t.seq between 0 and t.seq_inv/2
    ) [P&L 50%]
from mytable t
```

Comment: I don't really get how to implement this one, I'm trying, it seems to make sense should I add the partition by here as well?

Comment: This answer is correct, according to the sample data.

Comment: I have added the code but the results are counting for all rows apparently, not just the ones I want, as is giving me results over 700 (when the values should be around 2 to 10)

Comment: @GMB I think window functions *can* do this.  `sum of rows 5 to 9` is equal to `sum of rows 5 to infinity` minus `sum of rows 10 to infinity`?  So, in one CTE, create a cumulative sum column, and in the next CTE use `LEAD()` to find and deduct the appropriate value?  *(This feels badly worded, there's an answer here for smarter people than me to peer-review)*